# RxJava and Realm request make app skip frame

Tags: android, realm, rx-java2, android-threading

I'm using RxJava and Realm database in an android project. But sometimes pressing a button is unresponsive and you have to do that many times for it to work sometime, and android log is saying xxx frame skipped. I know it has something to do with misusing UI thread. Here's some of my request, can someone tell me what's wrong with them?  Realm wants me to perform IO request on the same thread I'm using the response(not too sure though).

```
public Flowable<List<ClothingItem>> getClothingItemsLocal() {
    return Flowable.just(dbProvider.getClothingItems(mSortType));
}

public Flowable<List<ClothingItem>> getClothingItemsRemote() {
    return clothingService.getAll("Bearer " + preferencesManager.getToken())
            .map(response -> response.items)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSuccess(clothingItems -> {
                dbProvider.clearClothingItems();
                dbProvider.saveOrUpdateClothingItems(clothingItems);
            })
            .toFlowable()
            .map(remoteItems -> dbProvider.getClothingItems(mSortType));
}

public Flowable<ClothingItem> getClothingItem(@NonNull final String id) {
    return getClothingItemRemote(id)
            .startWith(dbProvider.getClothingItem(id))
            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> dbProvider.getClothingItem(id));
}
```

getAll method with retrofit.

```
@GET(BuildConfig.BASE_API_PATH + "clothing_items")
Single<GetClothingItemsResponseModel> getAll(@Header("Authorization") String token);
```

Realm provider methods:

```
public void saveOrUpdateEvents(List<Event> data) {
    realmInstance.executeTransaction(realm -> {
        for (Event event : data) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(event.date)) {
                Date date = DateUtils.getFullDate(event.date);
                Timber.d("date %s", date.toString());
                event.timestamp = date;
            }
            Event cashedEvent = getEvent(event.id);
            if (cashedEvent.id != null) {
                event.eventClothingItems = cashedEvent.eventClothingItems;
                event.tags = cashedEvent.tags;
                event.location = cashedEvent.location;
            }
        }
        realm.delete(Event.class);
        realm.insertOrUpdate(data);
    });
}



public void clearClothingItems() {
    realmInstance.executeTransaction(realm -> {
        realm.delete(ClothingItem.class);
    });
}
```

Comment: IMHO I'd recommend you `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` and `.observeOn(Schedulers.io())`  before the `.map`.

Comment: There are two map functions, before which one?

Comment: I'd say before both of them, I am not an expert, but you could try that.

Comment: This is because your `dbProvider` does not take into account that Realm instances are thread-local, and so you are bound to the UI thread. But I'd have to modify the code in `dbProvider` to fix this issue.

Comment: Modify it how? what should I change

Comment: Add the code for dbProvider.clearClothingItems();
                dbProvider.saveOrUpdateClothingItems(clothingItems); and I'll tell you

Comment: I added them. Please have a look

Comment: What's wrong with these two methods please? dbProvider.clearClothingItems(); dbProvider.saveOrUpdateClothingItems(clothingItems);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Flowable<List<ClothingItem>> getClothingItemsRemote() {
    return clothingService.getAll("Bearer " + preferencesManager.getToken())         
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())   
            .map(response -> response.items) 
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSuccess(clothingItems -> {
                dbProvider.clearClothingItems();
                dbProvider.saveOrUpdateClothingItems(clothingItems);
            })     
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .toFlowable()
            .map(remoteItems -> dbProvider.getClothingItems(mSortType));
}
```

Comment: I'm having this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.`

Comment: @Dr4ketheb4dass I've edited the answer, also can you add the code for `getAll()` method?

Comment: I added the getAll() method, and made the changes, but I still have the same error

Comment: Where exactly do you get that error? Any line? Can you also share the realm related code?

Comment: Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created"

Comment: You need to open the Realm on the background thread to use it on the background thread (and then you must also strictly ensure that it is properly closed once you are done)